# Wordpress meta_key structure - read and write

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I'm programing a php function in wordpress and in some point I have to add + 1 in the value of "option_rsv_t", the meta_key is in the following structure:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:9:{s:13:"option_name_t";s:7:"Spartan";s:14:"option_price_t";s:3:"100";s:12:"option_qty_t";s:2:"16";s:12:"option_rsv_t";s:1:"0";s:20:"option_default_qty_t";s:1:"1";s:17:"option_qty_t_type";s:8:"inputbox";s:20:"option_sale_end_date";s:10:"2021-10-19";s:20:"option_sale_end_time";s:5:"18:00";s:22:"option_sale_end_date_t";s:16:"2021-10-19 18:00";}}
```

Is there a php function to easily read and write into this string?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation using standard meta_data fields, I found that this data is "serialized" data and php already have 2 functions to work with this:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php